# React Native and Redux: pagination / infinite scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, socket.io, react-redux

I'm dealing with an issue right now which concerns the pagination.
I'm using websocket to transfer all the data.
And when I'm on my app, it sends me a request to collect the data that I need.

Websocket's results are something like:

```
{
    "next_page": 2,
    "page": 1,
    "per_page": 10,
    "prev_page": null,
    "result": [...],
    "total": 107,
    "total_pages": 11
}
```

When I scroll at the bottom, it sends me another request to collect the following results. The problem is that it doesn't send me the new results that I'm asking for in addition of the previous results that I already have. It only erases the first results that I want to keep and  it replaces them with the newest one.
I tried to solve it, but fail everytime.
This is what I have right now in the reducer:

```
case 'select':
    return {...state, payload: {...state.payload, ...action.data}}
```

I would like to change the value of the object and add the 10 new results right after the previous ones in the results board.

Can anyone here help me with this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Who are 'it' in 'it sends me ...' and 'They' in 'They deliver me..' ?

Comment: Where & Why you do:
return {...state, payload: {...state.payload, ...action.data}}
why you affect the payload ? I guess the problem comes from there...

Comment: @BinaryMan The websocket sends me the data from the API
This is what I mean by saying "they deliver me" ^^